# My proxy webservice is missing one method from the real webservice?

Tags: web-services, proxy, wsdl

I can browse to the urls for both my proxy webservice and my actual webservice and I am missing one method between my proxy service and my actual account service?
I've tried a lot of things and cannot get my proxy to show the same methods. I don't know how to generate the wsdl file that maps the methods and I can even see the file is missing the method and the file is a file from TFS that I downloaded to build my website on the first day I started working here.

I'm trying to change the generated file by hand but its not working. When I do a find on my computer for svcutil or wsdl it comes up with nothing. Is there a special computer I need to be able to run these utilities?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://account.hse.org/GetUserNameByMembershipId.
>     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
>     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
>     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
>     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://account.hse.org/GetUserNameByMembershipId.
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

Source Error:

Line 197:        public string GetUserNameByMembershipId(int membershipID)
Line 198:        {
Line 199:            object[] results = this.Invoke("GetUserNameByMembershipId", new object[] {
Line 200:                        membershipID});
Line 201:            return ((string)(results[0]));

Source File: c:\TFS\IT\Web\HseStore.org\HseStore\Hse.Sso.Client\Proxies\AuthServiceProxy.cs    Line: 199

Stack Trace:

[SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://account.hse.org/GetUserNameByMembershipId.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +503338
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +215
   Vfw.Sso.Client.Proxies.AuthServiceProxy.GetUserNameByMembershipId(Int32 membershipID) in c:\TFS\IT\Web\HseStore.org\HseStore\Hse.Sso.Client\Proxies\AuthServiceProxy.cs:199
   Vfw.Sso.Client.Helpers.AuthServiceHelper.GetUserNameByMembershipId(Int32 membershipID) in c:\TFS\IT\Web\HseStore.org\HseStore\Hse.Sso.Client\Helpers\AuthServiceHelper.cs:103
   OMS.CreateAccount.btnCreateAccount_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\TFS\IT\Web\MAIN\OMSDomain\OMS\CreateAccount.aspx.cs:63
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +124
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Answer (score 0):

are you using Visual Studio? 
an easy way to regenerate the proxy is to remove the service reference and re-add it.

If you need to generate the proxy manually then you need svcutil and this link will tell you how to get it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

In short, you need the Windows Sdk and then you can find svcutil at this path : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin

Comment: ok, then right click, add service reference, point it to your service, once the reference is created, it will generate the proxy for you and you should be able to see your method there.

Comment: I did what you asked and I'm still getting the Soap error I've just appended to my original question.

Comment: This path does not exist on my computer: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin??? there is a v6.0A but it doesn't have a bin folder?